# What does the "percentage sign" mean in the Vue.js source code

Tags: vue.js, flowtype

I am reading Vue.js's source code([here](https://github.com/vuejs/vue/blob/dev/src/shared/util.js#L41)) on github and stumbled upon something both I don't know and can't find an answer.

A related part from the source:

```
export function isObject (obj: mixed): boolean %checks {
  return obj !== null && typeof obj === 'object'
}
```

What is the function or meaning of the "%"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a Flow feature called [Predicate Function](https://flow.org/en/docs/types/functions/#toc-predicate-functions).

In short, it denotes a function performing a type refinement.

In the specific example, it means that Flow knows that when a value is tested positively using `isObject`, it will be of type `object`.

Flow has some baked-in checks to refine a type, including things like `obj !== null` and `typeof obj === 'object'`, but if you extract it to a generic `isObject` function returning `boolean`, Flow won't trust that the function is performing a type refinement, unless you mark it with `%checks`.

Note that TypeScript has a similar feature called [User-Defined Type Guards](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#UserDefinedTypeGuards).